# Как вызвать событие сохранения модели Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Есть модель Model/Article которая наследуется от Model/Base/Article нужно как то поймать событие сохранения модели и добавить условие, если в моделе обновилось поле title то в этот момент отправить http запрос, в моделе есть

```
public function save(ConnectionInterface $con = null)
```

Но как им оперировать я не могу понять, заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Используйте [стандартные механизмы](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html) подписки на сообщения?

Answer (score 1):

В [данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1398996/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-symfony) дал описание, как подключить Listener. Более подробно, можно прочитать в [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-entity-listeners) к Symfony.

В общем, создайте и зарегистрируйте слушатель для конкретной сущности или же подписчик, для сразу всех сущностей, далее, в нем вам будут доступны все сервисы через Dependecy Injection (параметры конструктора).